# "From" in php mail $headers not passing

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I have a mail script that was working fine and I can't figure out what changed that's not causing the "from" to pass.

I have this code in a mail function

```
$to = ($_POST['email']);
$subject = 'Welcome to the Team!';
$url = 'mydomain.com'; 
$headers = "From: info@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "BCC: me@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
...
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The problem is, when the email comes through, the "from" looks like this:

> From: (mydomain)@(someletters&numbers).shr.phx3.(myhost).net

instead of ...

> From: info@mydomain.com

What's up?

---

UPDATE WITH FULL CODE

```
...
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$to = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>…Email Message 1…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$to = ($_POST['email']);
$subject = 'Subject';
$url = 'mydomain.caom'; 
$headers = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>…Email Message 2…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL='.$url.'">';
}
```

Comment: @B McCarthy , coz you are just overwriting your `$headers` every time, try to concatenate it with `$headers.`, see `.` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headers are broken and need to be concatenated using a dot after the first declaration:

```
$headers = "From: info@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: me@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

---

**Edit:**

Rename your second set of headers to `$headers`, for example:

```
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$to = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message .= "<html><body>…Email Message 1…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$to = ($_POST['email']);
$subject = 'Subject';
$url = 'mydomain.caom'; 
$headers2 = "From: me@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers2 .= "BCC: someonelese@ mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>…Email Message 2…</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers2);
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL='.$url.'">';
}
```

Comment: That causes a problem. I am running two separate mail functions / email messages and when I use the `.=` it causes Message A and Message B to be delivered to both recipients.

Comment: @BMcCarthy you'll need to post your full code then. that `...` could be anything.

Comment: @BMcCarthy you need to do the same thing for your 2nd set of headers as I did in my answer as per your original post. However, you could just use a different variable for the 2nd like `$headers2` and concatenate the same way I did here. I made an edit. Please reload it.

Comment: Thanks! Using a combination of your suggestions did the trick: `$headers2 .=`

Comment: @BMcCarthy You're welcome. We can close 'er up then and mark it as solved to also inform others that a solution has been found, *cheers*